# How to activate leuven-dark-theme?

Tags: themes

I have installed leuven with melpa a while ago and updated it as of 31st of August 2019. I found out there is a dark version. How do I activate it at loading of Emacs? I have tried:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path " ~/.emacs.d/elpa/leuven-theme-20190831.1008/")
(load-theme 'leuven-dark t)
```

Note that (load-theme 'leuven t) works for the light version. I have tried comparing leuven-theme.el and leuven-dark-theme.el but could not find a clue about what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add MELPA to your .emacs file

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
;; Comment/uncomment this line to enable MELPA Stable if desired.  See `package-archive-priorities`
;; and `package-pinned-packages`. Most users will not need or want to do this.
;;(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa-stable" . "https://stable.melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)
```

Restart Emacs.

Refresh package database and install the leuven theme:

```
M-x package-refresh-contents
M-x package-install leuven-theme
```

Add this startup hook to your .emacs file

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook
  (lambda ()
    (load-theme 'leuven-dark)
    ))
```

Restart Emacs again. Confirm that you want to run this theme ( asked only at the first start ).

Comment: I had to explicitly update it within the list-packages framework. Anything I tried that circumvented that would go back to the older version of Leuven. Thank you for giving me essentially another push to look back at it :)

Comment: This is the only method that worked for me. ( Latest Emacs version on Windows 10. )
It's a nice theme anyway, so I tried everything until I found this solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to load leuven first and then switch to leuven-dark.So first do

```
  (load-theme 'leuven t)
```

Then load leuven-dark via

```
   M-x load-theme <RET> leuven-dark <RET>
```

Doing `M-x describe-variable <RET> custom-enabled-themes <RET>` shows that 'leuven-dark' is now installed.

My installation is via

```
 git clone git://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven-theme.git
```

I assume the same applies if you use the package manager.

Comment: I tried this and still got the same error: 

"error: Unknown theme ‘leuven’ "

Comment: I've altered my answer as above. Seem to work.

Comment: still doesn't work for me with your updated answer :(

Comment: Are you using the package from (MELPA?) or from git? I don't use any packages from MELPA since over the years I've had numerous installation problems with them.

Comment: it was MELPA. But I tried to install it over git (first having uninstalled my MELPA version), following your advice. But still no success.

Comment: I'm having the same issue and the solution above also doesn't work for me. I opened a ticket in the repo: https://github.com/fniessen/emacs-leuven-theme/issues/67